# Jenkins Pipeline error when building

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have been trying to get Pipeline working on Jenkins 2.107 however it keeps coming up with an error that i have struggled to locate online. We have a Windows 2008 R2 server with Jenkins running as a service.

I have installed the pipeline plugin and set up the Hello World provided to test it. As soon s it starts to build it throws this error to the console.

> Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY [BFA] Scanning build
>   for known causes... [BFA] No failure causes found [BFA] Done. 0s
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor  at
>   jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
>     at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1327)
>     at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) Caused:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/kohsuke/groovy/sandbox/GroovyInterceptor  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory.makeClassLoader(CpsGroovyShellFactory.java:113)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory.build(CpsGroovyShellFactory.java:119)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:556)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:520)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:319)
>     at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) Finished: FAILURE

We are running Java 8 and i have set Jenkins to use Java 8 in the config file. I have researched this error but can't seem to find something similar.

We have another server which runs pipeline fine however the differences are that this is windows 2012 server and it is running an older version of Jenkins and Java. Other than the two differences all plugins and config match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error and resolved it by upgrading the Script Security plugin to version 1.44 (had 1.41).

Comment: Thank you for this response, it worked with the upgrade to the new Script Security Plugin. Many Thanks